# The password in my router's settings backup file looks strange

Tags: router, backup, encryption, passwords

I've got this SilverCrest Repeater model Swv 733 A2 (uses a Mediatek MT7628 chip, as it seems) and I wanted to dump the settings after I configured it, to have a backup.
The backup file is a text file with the extension .dat, so I was able to open it and I've seen two password fields: one for the normal login, to say so, and another one for the first-time login (admin/admin).

This is ow the fields looked after I saved my settings:

```
Login=78    dnc``a
Password=!  aee d
  'Login_def'='admin'
  'Password_def'='admin'
```

Now, you can see two things there: the "normal" login has no quotes (almost all settings in the file are with quotes) and the string for username and password seem encrypted. Obviously, when I tried to load back this file, I could not login anymore.
I thought to see how the original file was looking like, so I dumped a settings file from the initial configuration, no alteration at all. And this is what I got:

```
Login=72;?8
Password=72;?8
  'Login_def'='admin'
  'Password_def'='admin'
```

Even here it's clear that the "user defined credentials" is not just blank, though it's not supposed to have any password or username set just yet.

This causes me big problems due to the fact that I cannot use a backup to restore my router's settings, nor I can add custom settings to the router that aren't visible in the GUI and can be only altered in this file.

I tried to comment the "user defined credentials", i tried to set a plain text password, I tried it with and without quotes, but every time, I wasn't able to login after I loaded the file.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Suggest update the firmware? Return it? Sounds buggy since it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Well, its routing options were very basic, as it was supposed to be used as an extender or access point.
But as I could see from the config file that it actually has the full features of a regular router, I was thinking what if it's actually possible to benefit of those features.
Unfortunately I couldn't find anything anywhere about how other routers have this written in their settings file, so i could try some... I was hoping that people would offer some possible examples, or ways to try.

Comment: My best suggestion would be to look for alternative firmware, like something OpenWRT / DD-WRT based, like Tomat,  and then you can go crazy with tons of settings & things. Could even turn a cheap basic router into a repeater or extender, not to mention run whatever servers you'd prefer, VPN, limit bandwidth of programs/users, etc...